# PHP Sockets not loading on Centos 5

Tags: php, centos

So I ran `sudo yum install php-common` to install php-sockets, but phpinfo() is still not showing sockets loaded after restarting apache, and trying a socket_create() in php throws a function not defined error.

I tried adding `extension=sockets.so` to my php.ini (verified correct php.ini via phpinfo), but it just throws an extension not found on startup, and doing a find / -name 'sockets.so' yields no results.

What gives? Any ideas on what to check next?

Comment: Just for completeness, I'm confirming that [`php-sockets` should be part of `php-common`](http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/).

Comment: @Tomalak See my comment please.

Comment: @SIFE: Regardless, it's supposed to be part of the package. If it's not there, something's wrong. A citation from some repository that their `php-common` doesn't include `php-sockets` would be great.

Answer (score -2):

**UPDATE:** Its look like some repository don't include `php-socket` in their `php-common` package. So you can either add another repository include `php-socket` in their `php-common` package, or install PHP from source and activate socket from the configuration:

```
./configure --enable-sockets
make && make install
```

Comment: So the rpm description is just incorrect? `$ rpm -q --provides php-common | grep sock` returns: `php-sockets`

Comment: @opsguy Its look like some repository's don't include `php-socket` in their packages, because I run in situation where `php-socket` extension not loaded, and to fix that I built `PHP` from source.

Comment: If your repository doesn't include `php-socket` for whatever reason, the solution is not to abandon managed packages for your _entire_ PHP installation, but to switch to a better repository. [This one](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3?stat=3&search=php-common&srodzaj=3&dist\[\]=55) explicitly includes `php-sockets` in `php-common`, as it's supposed to.